# Lectura/integracion de varios archivos grandes con R y Rstudio

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, table, read

Hola tengo 12 archivos cvs la mayoría pesa arriba de 120 MB, quise leerlos y unirlos en Rstudio cloud (me sucede lo mismo con la version de escritorio) y no he podido, logro la lectura de 5 archivos y no continua con los demás, me manda el mensaje "Error: Error occurred during transmission" y una ventana "the previous r session was abnormally terminated due to an unexpected crash" y se me reinicia RStudio. Alguien podría ayudarme a saber porque sucede y como podría solucionarlo? Intente con excel pero sobrepaso su capacidad de 1 millón de filas, tengo 5.7 millones de filas.

```
library(readr)
library(data.table)
path <- '/cloud/project'
setwd(path)
files <- list.files(pattern = '*.csv')
files
d202202 <- read.csv(files[1])
d202203 <- read.csv(files[2])
d202204 <- read.csv(files[3])
d202205 <- read.csv(files[4])
d202206 <- read.csv(files[5])
d202207 <- read.csv(files[6])
d202208 <- read.csv(files[7])
d202209 <- read.csv(files[8])
d202210 <- read.csv(files[9])
d202211 <- read.csv(files[10])
d202212 <- read.csv(files[11])
d202301 <- read.csv(files[12])
```

Comment: Me suena a que se trata de un problema de memoria Por lo que cuentas del proceso necesitas al menos la memoria RAM suficiente para manejar  el doble de los 5.7 millones de filas, aunque depende de como estés haciendo el proceso de carga, puede que necesites muchos más. Ten en cuenta que Rstudio Cloud, al menos la versión gratuita tiene un limite de memoria incluso más bajo que el de un equipo de escritorio.

Comment: Primer tema que deberías analizar, antes que importar los datos, ¿tienes memoria suficiente para manejar 5.7 millones de filas? si la tuvieras, entonces tendría sentido importar los datos, el tema es como lo estás haciendo, desconozco por que no publicaste nada de código. Una alternativa para "juntar" archivos es no usar R sino las  herramientas del SO para juntar físicamente cada uno, pero depende que el formato sea siempre el mismo y eliminar eventualmente cabeceras repetidas.

Comment: Te sugiero: edita la pregunta y agrega (1) un ejemplo de las dos primeras líneas de dos archivos, (2) muestranos el código que estás usando para importar los CSV.

Comment: Y me olvidaba, Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Gracias por aclararme lo de la capacidad de procesamiento y sugerencias, estoy iniciando y saltan muchas dudas.

Comment: Por el código que muestras, no hay ninguna optimización posible así que casi seguro el problema es de falta de memoria. En R todos los objetos nativos que se cargan van a parar a la memoria RAM.  Podrías verificarlo, cargando de un archivo por vez y en cada paso monitorear la memoria (Si usas Rstudio tienes un botón con varios reportes en la solapa enviroment), en algún momento seguramente llenaste la memoria y ahí empiezan los problemas.

Comment: Lamentablemente la única solución es conseguir más memoria, si es un equipo de escritorio, se agrega bancos de memoria, si es uno virtual tal vez puedas contratar más memoria. El otro camino es más complejo, optimizar el proceso para minimizar los requerimientos. No te puedo decir mucho por que no sé que es lo que piensas hacer con esos 12 data.frames, pero puedo sugerirte algunas coas: ¿Necesitas cargar todos al mismo tiempo o puedes hacer lo que tengas que hcer con cada data.frame de a uno por vez ? ¿Necesitas todas las columnas del csv o solo algunas?

Comment: El proceso que tienes que hacer, ¿podría hacerse obteniendo los datos desde una base de datos tradicional, sqlite, mysql, sql server etc? ¿Necesitas todas las filas o eventualmente podrías obtener una muestra más pequeña para hacer el análisis?

Answer (score 0):

puedes convertir tus archivos `.csv` en `.rds` o `.RData` con la función `saveRDS()`, así tendrán menos pesos y será más fácil de leer, ejemplo:

## Guardando

```
saveRDS("datos.xlsx", "resultados.rds")
```

## Lectura de datos

```
readr::read_rds("resultados.rds")
```